# Describing automorphisms of a punctured unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Here is my attempt :

> Let $f \in \text {Aut}(D(0,1) \setminus \{0\})$.
>
> Since $f$ is bounded on a deleted neighborhood of $0$, function $f$
>   has a removable singularity at $0$. Since $f$ is bijective, we must
>   have $f(0)=0.$
>
> By Schwarz's lemma we get $|f(z)| \le |z|.$
>
> But $f^{-1} \in \text {Aut}(D(0,1) \setminus \{0\}) \; \text {and}
>  f^{-1}(0)=0 \Rightarrow |z|=|f^{-1}(f(z))| \le |f(z)|.$
>
> Thus $|f(z)|=|z| \Rightarrow f(z)=\lambda z \;$ for some $\lambda \in
>  \Bbb C$ and $|\lambda|=1$.
>
> We infer that all the elements of $\text {Aut}(D(0,1) \setminus \{0\})$ are
>   rotations.

---

Are my arguments correct?

Comment: I think you could be skipping over some details here somehow. The removable singularity result assumes holomorphicity, but a general automorphism of sets is not guaranteed to be holomorphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important missing detail is where you say "since $f$ is bijective, $f(0)=0$".

To explain what the problem is we need to  be a little more careful with the notation (in fact you made the error because you're actually using the notation "$f$" for two different things. Not to say your notation was bad, it's fairly standard, but that's where the error came from).

Say $D$ is the disk and $D'$ is the punctured disk. You're given $f:D'\to D'$. Now $f$ has a removable singularity at the origin, great. So $f$ *extends* to a function $F:D\to\Bbb C$.

Now when you say "since $f$ is a bijection..." you're actually referring to the new function $F$. You're given that $f:D'\to D'$ is a bijection - *how* do you know that $F$ is a bijection?

For that matter, how do you even know that $F(0)\in D$?

Hints: A certain very basic result that you use all the time shows that $|F(0)|<1$. So you have $F:D\to D$. Now you can use the Open Mapping Theorem to show that since $f$ is a bijection we must have $F(0)=0$.

Comment: Ah! I didn't see this coming. I am glad that I posted this question here. Thanks!

Comment: If $|F(0)| \gt 1$, then $F$ would be discontinuous. If $|F(0)|=1$, image of open set $D(0,1)$ would be $[D(0,1) \setminus \{0\}] \cup \{F(0)\}$ which is not open. Thus $|F(0)| \lt 1.$ If $F(0)=p \neq 0$, then $F(q)=p$ for some $q \in D(0,1) \setminus \{0\}$. By hausdorffness we can have two disjoint open sets $U,V$ containg $q,0$ respectively. Their union is open and so is it's image. Observe that $F(U) \cap F(V)$ can't be singleton. Since it's intersection of open sets. Thus we have a point $a \in F(U) \cap F(V)$ such that $F(b)=a=F(c)$ for some $b \in U$ and $c \in V$. Again a contradiction!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion one argument is missing: we have $|f(z)|=|z|$ for all $z \in D(0,1)$. Why we get $f(z)=\lambda z \;$ for some $ \lambda$ with $|\lambda|=1$ ?

Define $g : D(0,1) \to \mathbb C$ by $g(z)=f(z)/z$ if $z \ne 0$ and $g(0)=f'(0)$. Then $g$ is holomorphic and $|g(z)|=1$ for all $z \in D(0,1)$.

Hence $g(D(0,1))$ is not open, thus $g$ is constant.

Can you proceed ?

Comment: Oh yes yes. I am familiar with this. It's my bad that I mentioned very few details in my proof. Thanks!

Comment: That's part of the standard statement of the Schwartz Lemma...